# Laravel (Eloquent) equivalent of Mongoose's populate() method

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, mongoose, eloquent

I understand that this question may have more than one DBMS-related answer, but maybe not, so here it goes.

So, I need my app to asynchronously grab some data from the backend, say something like a `User` and his `Posts`. I am using Vue2 with Axios on the frontend, so that it would be nice to write something like:

```
mounted: function() {
    axios.get('/users')
        .then((response) => {
            this.users = response.data;
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            // Handle this
        });
}
```

The outcome I'd like to have is the `users` object in my VueVM's data to contain also an array of `posts` for each `User`. Currently I build a custom associative array in my backend-side controller as follows:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', $id)->get();
return json_encode(['user' => $user, 'posts' => $posts]);
```

Or, when feasible, I use the `has_many` method, which is also pretty handy, but I find this solution pretty ugly and lacking reusability.

With Mongoose and MongoDB I would use the `populate()` method, but I cannot find (that is I actually don't know how to search for it) an equivalent to this with Eloquent.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have defined a posts() relationship in your User model, when retrieving the users, you can eager load the related data:

```
$users = User::with('posts')->get();
```

or a specific User:

```
$user = User::with('posts')->find($id);
```

Then `$user->posts` would contain a collection of the related Post models.

I suggest you read through https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships

Comment: Yup, that was it. Sorry, I should have spent more time on the docs. For anyone looking for more in-depth information, the correct section is:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading